# Compare average values for labeled data in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mean

supposed my dataframe,

```
 Name  Num Label
0   K    10    0
1   K    21    0 
2   K    31    0
3   K    41    1
4   Y    9     0
5   Y    19    0
6   Y    14    1
7   B    33    0
8   B    43    0    
9   B    77    1
10  B    89    1
```

I would like to see the rate of increase in the mean value of data labeled 0 and data labeled 1.

**ex**,

```
K - label 0, mean = 20.67
K - label 1, mean = 41
```

so, `increased rate = (41-20.67) / 20.67 * 100 = 93.81%`

It may be added to a new column or a new data frame may be generated. Is there a possible way?

*The rate of rise is an example, and if the mean value of the data labeled 0 is greater, the value should be -(minus) value.

thank you for reading.

Comment: It seems typo `(41-20.67) / 21.67 * 100` - need `(41-20.67) / 20.67 * 100`

Comment: @jezrael yes It`s a mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with default function `mean` and then subtract and divide:

```
df1 = (df.pivot_table(index='Name',columns='Label', values='Num')
         .rename(columns={0:'mean_before',1:'mean_after'}))
df1['new'] = df1['mean_after'].sub(df1['mean_before']).div(df1['mean_before']).mul(100)
print (df1)
Label  mean_before  mean_after         new
Name                                      
B        38.000000        83.0  118.421053
K        20.666667        41.0   98.387097
Y        14.000000        14.0    0.000000
```

Comment: The pivot table function is new. I'm always thankful.

Comment: Can I change the index name? I try df1['0'] = df1['mean_before']

Comment: I want to get only the name list from the pivot table, but it is not possible with the normal dataframe column code. Is there a way?
For example, df1.name

Comment: @ybin - it is index, so need `df.index` or convert index to column by `df2 = df1.reset_index()` and then `df2['Name']` working